# How to use Google Material Symbols efficient? (without loading all icons)

Tags: css, deployment, fonts, google-fonts

I want to use [Google Material Symbols](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/material_symbols) in a React project.

When I include the font into my project it's working fine. However I noticed that it downloads the font with all 2,500 icons which is around 2,5MB big.

Now I struggle to find a good solution to reduce this load (or is it the font shared between websites?).

Here are my questions. Maybe someone can share his experience:

1. When I only want to use a few icons can I reduce the font used anyhow? (I wondered if there is for example a query to only include following icons)
2. Shall I just use it because it shares the font between websites? (so it makes the caching efficient)
3. Shall I split the icons in svgs and use them instead?
4. Are there any libraries which try to solve this problem?

Comment: 3 - yes: https://fonts.google.com/icons?hl=he customize the setting, choose icon and click download svg